# DOM parser for XML Edit, Update

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I'm thankful for ALL post that helps me to parse XML using DOM parser.

I have no idea about how to dynamically add data like below in my XML file using DOM parser, can anyone help me to get out of this.

Thank you.

```
<group
    android:name="Marker Group Left Front Wing Mirror Cover"
    android:scaleX="1"
    android:scaleY="1"
    android:translateX="1778.866765"
    android:translateY="331.3570720">
    <path
        android:name="Marker Red"
        android:fillColor="#ff0031"
        android:pathData="M36.387 0.355c-19.829 0 -35.959 16.13 -35.959 35.959 0 24.607 32.177 60.732 33.546 62.26 1.288 1.429 3.535 1.427 4.821 0 1.369 -1.526 33.551 -37.65 33.551 -62.26 0 -19.829 -16.13 -35.959 -35.959 -35.959zm0 54.053c-9.976 0 -18.093 -8.116 -18.093 -18.094 0 -9.976 8.117 -18.091 18.093 -18.091 9.978 0 18.095 8.115 18.095 18.091 0 9.978 -8.117 18.094 -18.095 18.094z" />
</group>
```

I want to add above data to following node stated below:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="1800"
android:viewportWidth="2880">

NEED TO ADD ABOVE group node HERE

</vector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few R & D on element and attribute, I finally found the solution.

```
Element group = doc.createElement("group");
    group.setAttribute("android:name", "Marker Group Left Front Wing Mirror Cover");
    group.setAttribute("android:scaleX", "1");
    group.setAttribute("android:scaleY", "1");
    group.setAttribute("android:translateX", "1778.866765");
    group.setAttribute("android:translateY", "331.3570720");

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    (here root is my vector in which i want to add group element)
    root.appendChild(group);
```

- above code will add the group to my vector.

  ```
  Element path = doc.createElement("path");
  path.setAttribute("android:name", "Marker Red");
  path.setAttribute("android:fillColor", "#ff0031");
  path.setAttribute("android:pathData", "M36.387 0.355c-19.829 0 -35.959 16.13 -35.959 35.959 0 24.607 32.177 60.732 33.546 62.26 1.288 1.429 3.535 1.427 4.821 0 1.369 -1.526 33.551 -37.65 33.551 -62.26 0 -19.829 -16.13 -35.959 -35.959 -35.959zm0 54.053c-9.976 0 -18.093 -8.116 -18.093 -18.094 0 -9.976 8.117 -18.091 18.093 -18.091 9.978 0 18.095 8.115 18.095 18.091 0 9.978 -8.117 18.094 -18.095 18.094z");


  root.getLastChild().appendChild(path);
  ```
- above code will add the path to my group, which is last child of root element vector.